# What's the best way to position interconnected nodes in a 2d graph?

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph, drawing, visualization

I have a list (graph?) of nodes, and each node is connected to other nodes in the list one or more times.  I want to take these nodes and lay them out in a nice 2d diagram with lines connecting them together in an optimal way.  What's the best algorithm for doing this so that they're spaced evenly apart and the lines connecting them are as untangled as possible?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518685/graph-drawing-algorithms-im-trying-to-render-finite-state-automata

Comment: I had searched before posting but obviously didn't use the right keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone implemented a force-directed graph in JavaScript and gave me permission to do what I want with it:  http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/bqr7v/force_directed_graph_layout_in_javascript/c0o4ka5?context=3

Answer (score 1):

Use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

If you want to learn more about the algorithms used, check out their [Theory](http://www.graphviz.org/Theory.php) section.

Here's an example from their [Gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php):
[image: GraphViz Example]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that it depends on the data your trying to represent as a graph. There isn't one that fits all.

See: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html - for some example layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a nice bunch of different infovis ideas https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery